# Is it acceptable to use single character variable or function name in javascript

Tags: javascript, coding-style

Current i have to do the code review and many javascript files our coder has coded the function like this

```
@param object o
@param string m
@return mixed

call:function(o, m){
    return o&&o[m]?o[m].apply(o, Ext.Array.slice(arguments, 2)):null;
},
```

I want to know that is it ok or the parameters to function should be more verbose to read like

`function (object, method)`

There are many places where he used variables and function like that

Comment: This is a personal matter of coding style.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about coding standards and belongs on either [codereview.se] or [programmers.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you're doing. In general, when you're writing functions and variables, you should never use single character variable names, with the sole exception of in loops, `i` or `j`, etc, etc, are perfectly acceptable. Otherwise, it just gets hard to read and messy, since you don't know what each of them are doing off of the top of your head. However, when you're pushing things into production, its often helpful to minify it, and one thing that happens when you minify it is that the variable and function names get as short as possible.

Comment: I would say this is correct in general.  In physics, however, certain quantities are referenced by single variables (e.g. E = m c squared) and would be well known to physics people.

Answer (score 1):

For me is prefer to use functions

like this..

```
 function sample( o, i, n ) {
  //code here


   }
   // this is to call the object created
  var test = sample(for_o, For_i, for_n);
```

hope this will help